# How to use protocol properly to call a GameViewController's function?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-protocols

I have a GameScene.sks, GameScene class and GameViewController. I can create a protocol without using sks but I want to do this using `SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`.

When I use `scene.gameDelegate = self` in GameViewController, viewDidload()
 I'm getting `Value of type 'SKScene' has no member gameDelegate` error.

How Can I overcome this problem?

```
protocol GameDelegate {

    func createAds()
}
```

GameScene class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var gameDelegate: GameDelegate!

    ...
```

GameViewController viewDidLoad:

```
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                scene.gameDelegate = self // Value of type 'SKScene' has no member gameDelegate

                gameState = .playing
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the local variable `scene` as your `GameScene` subclass of `SKScene`.
This would look something like:

```
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        // change type of optionally bound constant 'scene'
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            scene.gameDelegate = self 

            gameState = .playing
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    }
```

Also ensure that the `GameViewController` class conforms to the `GameDelegate` protocol and implements all of the required interface methods.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried many things without that. You saved my time.

Comment: @tobeiosdev Absolutely, glad I could help.